# How i get parameter from url in zf2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-controller

I am new in zf2 and I want to get parameter from url. But when I write

```
if($this->getRequest()->isGet()) {
                $get = $this->params()->fromQuery();
            }
            print_r($get);
```

in controller it returns empty array. How I get parameter from url? Here is my url:

http://test.zeptosystems.com/event/create/46/1396465200/1

I want to get 46. How can I get this parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In controller you can do that with Params plugin:

```
$this->params()->fromQuery();
```

But `fromQuery` returns standard `GET` params  from part `?var=value&var2=somevalue`. 
Because you have nice urls you should use

```
$this->params()->fromRoute();
```

See [Reference of Params class](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Mvc.Controller.Plugin.Params.html) or [ZF2 Manual Controller's plugins page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-params) for more details

Answer (score -3):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class FooController extends Controller
{

// stuff

    public function showAction(){

        // and to show http req
        $req = new Request();
        $foo = $req->get('foo');

        return new Response('Get Parameter -> '.$foo);

    }
}
```

Comment: Symfony's class in ZF2 project? Really? Why? ;-)